# How do I convert this code from axios to useSWR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I have a custom hook "useCart" to get the cart, but I have multiple API's to call and they are dependent on each other. I have written code using axios but I want it using useSWR because I am using mutate funtion from useSWR everywhere.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (logged === true && token !== null) {
        axios
          .post(apis?.create_cart, null, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          })
          .then(() => {
            axios
              .get(apis?.create_cart, {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              })
              .then((res) => {
                setCart(res.data);
              });
          });
      } else if (logged === false && token === null) {
        const guest_cart_id = window.localStorage.getItem("guest_cart_id");
        if (guest_cart_id === null) {
          axios.post(apis?.create_guest_cart).then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem("guest_cart_id", res.data);
            axios
              .get(apis?.get_guest_cart + "/" + res.data + "/items")
              .then((res) => {
                setCart(res.data);
              });
          });
        } else {
          axios.post(apis?.create_guest_cart).then((res) => {
            axios
              .get(apis?.get_guest_cart + "/" + guest_cart_id + "/items")
              .then((res) => {
                setCart(res.data);
              });
          });
        }
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [logged, token]);
```

I have tried the below but its not returning any data. I think its because of the custom hook or synchronous operation.

```
const createCart = async (url) => {
    console.log("creating cart");
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw await res.json();
    }
    return await res.json();
  };

  const getCart = async (url) => {
    console.log("getting cart");
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw await res.json();
    }
    return await res.json();
  };

  const { data: createCartData, error: createCartError } = useSWR(
    token ? apis?.create_cart : null,
    createCart
  );
  const { data: getCartData, error: getCartError } = useSWR(
    createCartData ? apis?.get_cart : null,
    getCart
  );
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: I have edited, please check @vighnesh153